# C# Static Classes & Scope

Tags: c#

I am just wondering why can't I define a static class as protected, private etc?

```
protected static class Class1 {}
```

The compiler gives the following error message:

> Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal

Comment: This is not specific to static classes. It applies to all elements defined in a namespace. Static classes can be private or protected (unless they are defined in a namespace).

Comment: @Oded no I didn't add it, its the error thats given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it doesn't make sense to have a private or protected member in a namespace. A namespace is not an isolated unity like a class so that a private member makes sense. A namespace can't be inherited, so there is no use for protected members.

You can have a private or proteted static class inside another class:

```
public class X {

  private static class Y { }

  protected static class Z { }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-nested classes in C# can be [public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or [internal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) but not [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx). `protected` is a member access modifier and does not apply to types defined at the namespace level.

Comment: They can be `private` or `protected` as well, if not declared directly in a namespace (ie. nested classes).

Comment: @klausbskov: if they are nested classes they can.

Answer (score 0):

I am just citing the appropriate clause from C# specification:

> Top-level types, which are not nested
>   in other types, can only have internal
>   or public accessibility. The default
>   accessibility for these types is
>   internal